# Phonegap dial with Fallback

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, iso

I am building a phonegap application that has a few buttons to start phone calls.  The issue i am having is that not all devices will be capable of making the call.  I also played around with setting times and canceling but there seems to be no way to tell if the activity started.

I am building for android and ios.  If anyone has any thoughts or recommendations, i would greatly appreciate it.

example of what i want to happen:

```
<script>
    function call(p) {
        if([can make a phone call])
            window.location = p;
        else
            alert(p);
    };
</script>

<button onclick="call('tel:1234567890')">Call</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/anemitoff/PhoneGap-PhoneDialer/

Even has an error callback. Might display your phone number there on error. IOS and android supported